# How can I use a piped string of commands with Python subprocess module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I want to partition a new, blank disk using a Python script on Ubuntu.

In a bash script or from the command line, this would do the job:

```
$echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | sudo fdisk /dev/X
```

where X is the HDD in question.

I have tried to port this into a Python script using the subprocess module, as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdString, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
                     close_fds=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
stdoutAndErr = p.communicate()
```

where `cmdString` is just the same `"echo -e ..."` string above.

This doesn't work though. Output is just `fdisk` printing out the command options, so it clearly doesn't like what I am sending it.

What's wrong with the above simple approach to life?

Comment: If you want to format something as code, indent it by 4 spaces. Don't use `<code>`-tags.

Comment: @Space_COwbOy OK. what are <code> tags for then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'batteries included' [pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html) module may be what you are looking for.  Doug Hellman has a nice [write-up](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pipes/) on how to use it to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a complex command string to the Popen() function.  It takes a list as the first argument.  The [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) module, particularly the split() function, will help you a lot, and the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) documentation has some examples that use it.

So you'd want something like:

```
import shlex, subprocess
command_line = 'echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw\n" | sudo fdisk /dev/X'
args = shlex.split(command_line)
p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

Comment: Odd. I am experiencing some deja vu there. I could have sworn someone else answered that same suggestion and I commented already saying it didn't work. Anyway, it didn't work. But now I think I know why the shlex business doesn't work. It treats the first word "echo" as the command, and everything else including the pipe character as arguments to that. So all it does is an echo. If you add "shell=True" to the Popen argument list, it does something else mysterious, which just returns a "\n" character, but still does nothing to partition tables.

Comment: Hang about :-) It appears I have to do this in two steps ... one for the echo command and one for the fdisk ... and hook them up via explicit subprocess.PIPEs

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two pipes actually, the input of the second pipe would be the output of the first one, so here's what to do:

```
 p=subprocess.Popen(['printf','n\np\n1\n\n\nw\n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 p1=subprocess.Popen(['fdisk','/dev/X'],stdin=p.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE).wait()
```

Bonus: notice the wait() , this way your script will wait for the fdisk to finish.