# How can I execute shell command with a | pipe in it

Tags: python, shell

I am using python's subprocess `call()` to execute shell command.
It works for a single command.
But what if my shell command calls a command and pipe it to another command.

I.e. how can I execute this in python script?

```
grep -r PASSED *.log | sort -u | wc -l
```

I am trying to use the Popen way, but i always get 0 as output

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(("xxd -p " + filename).split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("tr -d \'\\n\'".split(), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(("grep -c \'"+search_str + "\'").split(), stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p2.stdout.close()  # Allow p2 to receive a SIGPIPE if p3 exits.
output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

When I try the command in shell,it returns 1

```
 xxd -p file_0_4.bin | tr -d '\n'  | grep -c 'f5dfddd239'
```

I always get 0. Even if I get 1 when I type the same command at shell.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Call with `shell=True` argument. For example,

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('grep -r PASSED *.log | sort -u | wc -l', shell=True)
```

---

### Hard way

```
import glob
import subprocess

grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-r', 'PASSED'] + glob.glob('*.log'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-u'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
exit_status = subprocess.call(['wc', '-l'], stdin=sort.stdout)
```

See [Replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Comment: I used your easy way. It works. But as soon as I switch from 'subprocess.call' to 'subprocess.checkout', I get this error " returned non-zero exit status 1'. The command I want to execute is 'xxd -p afile | grep -c 'astring''. When i execute on the shell, it prints 1 if exists 0 if does not exists.

Comment: @michael, I got it. `check_output` raise exception if command exit with non-zero status code. `grep` exit with 0 if match found, non-zero  otherwise. So, just use `call` unless you want such feature.

Comment: i Posted my code when using the hard way. Unfortunately call does not work for me since I have "|" in my command.

Comment: @michael, How about `subprocess.call(r"xxd -p test.png  | tr -d '\n' | grep -c 26eddbb72f7", shell=True)`?

Comment: @michael, or `print subprocess.Popen(r"xxd -p test.png  | tr -d '\n' | grep -c 26eddbb72f7", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]`

Comment: that works. but I need to get the result of what grep returns 1 means exists 0 means not exist.

Comment: @michael, `Popen(..).communicate()[0]` version will return `'1\n'` as you expected. Do `.strip()` if you want to get only `'1'`.

Comment: @michael, I tested it, and it print occurrence count. I couldn't reproduce get-nothing case.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers would work. But here's a more elegant approach, IMO, which is to use [`plumbum`](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/).

```
from plumbum.cmd import grep, sort, wc
cmd = grep['-r']['PASSED']['*.log'] | sort['-u'] | wc['-l']  # construct the command
print cmd() # run the command
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4368818/2036917) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089368/how-can-i-use-a-piped-string-of-commands-with-python-subprocess-module?rq=1) That is use "subprocess" with shell=True